# grid 2 crashing on laptop

Tags: technical-issues, grid-2

after playing one or two races when next event is loading the game crashes suddenly without any warning or showing any problem windows **not** even show the dialog box "grid 2 exe has stopped working"

- using windows 8 - 64 bit 4gb ram 2gb graphic card [AMD RADEON ] 2.7 ghz intel i5 processor

Comment: I found [this](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1358388) as a fix for Win 7 using i7. It seems to be a rather common hardware-related problem, apparently.